# Find my own product ratings via Amazon API

Tags: scrape, amazon-mws

I need to find my product details such as ratings without scraping.

Is that possible or any existing API to get these information from?

If not is it possible to scrape it by my self any good source for free node js amazon scraper?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There does exist an API called [Amazon's product advertising API.](https://webservices.amazon.com/paapi5/documentation/register-for-pa-api.html)

The problem with it is that you need an [Amazon associate account](https://affiliate-program.amazon.com/) which is an affiliate marketing program that expects you to drive sales to products.

> Product Advertising API sign up is available only to associates who have referred qualified sales and have been accepted into the program.

You could use the Keepa API. Keepa is a browser widget that scrapes Amazon through its users. The downside here is the data may not be real time. The more active an item is, the more often it is scraped. You can pull price, offers, reviews, rating, and more. The plugin is free, but the API is not.

Comment: Have you tried this scraper module?
https://www.npmjs.com/package/amazon-asin-scraper